# Show that A has a model with infinitely many elements

Tags: logic

Let $A$ be a first order logic formula with the property that, for every even number $n$ there exists a model $M=(D,I)$ such that $M \vDash A$ and $|D|=n$.
Show that A has a Model with infinitely many elements in it.

I tried using compactness theorem. But i dont know how i should define my subsets. Any tip would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: You need to expand you formulas you are working with: Try writing down a formula that says "there are at least $n$ objects". Consider how you can use these formulas to make a theory that would imply that there are infinitely many objects. Show that that theory with your original one $A$ is satisfiable.

Comment: @James but where would the part come in where we use that n is even ?

Comment: That is a bit of a red herring; A fuller statement of the theorem is: If $\Gamma$ is a theory which has models of arbitrarily large finite size, then $\Gamma$ has an infinite model.

Comment: @James by conjunction of formulas. A has at least 2 elements, A has at least 4 elements etc We can create a model that is infinite ?

Comment: You can't take that conjunction because it is over an infinite set of formulas and first-order logic only allows finite formulas. However, you don't need to have only one formula, you need a set of formulas to which you will apply the compactness theorem.

Comment: @James So i just take the set of those formulas ? But why is every subset satisfiable though ? Im sorry im not understanding well.

Comment: You're doing fine! I'm deliberately being a bit vague. Yes you can put all those formulas into one set. This allows you to cheat your way around am infinite conjunction. Now, a model for this infinite set and A is precisely an infinite model of A, which is what we want. To show it is satisfiable it suffices to show it is finitely satisfiable (by compactness). So take a finite subset of this collection. Use your hypotheses to show it is satisfiable.

Comment: Thank you @James i think i understood :)   You can put your first comment as answer and ill accept